# Django: the post isn't selected automatically of particular user

Tags: python, django

hi am working on a project where am using multiple user data 
a user did a post onto the site and when driver see that post he adds their offer to that post but when driver submit the post ...at the admin level the particular is selected automatically but the post  is not selected on which he adds price 
this is my post model.py

```
class Loader_post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,related_name="Loader")
    pick_up_station = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    destination_station = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    sender_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    receiver_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

this is my second model of adding price to a particular post

```
class price(models.Model):
    my_post = models.ManyToManyField(Loader_post, related_name='prices')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True, default='')
    driver_price = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    driver_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    approved_price = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

this is my adding price to the post views.py

```
@login_required
def add_price_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Loader_post, pk=pk)
    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = price_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ps = form.save(commit=False)
            ps.user = request.user
            ps.status = True
            ps.post =  post
            ps.save()
            return redirect('Driver:Driverview')
    else:
        form = price_form()
    return render(request, 'price_form.html', {'form': form})
```

this is my html  add post button

```
{% for loader in Loader %}
```

this is loop
and this is button

```
<a href="{% url 'Driver:price' pk=loader.pk %}" class="btn btn-full">add price</a>
```

[image: as u can see the two user have different post but it is not selected automatically]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a ManyToMany relation between `price` and `Loader_post` model, hence `ps.post =  post` won't work. You need to use [**`add()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) method to add new post. Like this:

```
ps.save()
ps.my_post.add(post)
```

Comment: "<price: 1200>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Comment: ....thank you soooooo much sir ... it is a big relief for me...it is working properly